# How to name a range so that it doesn't automatically change when rows are added in between

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-named-ranges

Is there a way to name a range so that it doesn't automatically change when rows are added in between?

Ex: Range1 = `'Sheet1'!K5:K36`
Add a row between rows 6&7 and now this automatically changes to 
Range1 = `'Sheet1'!K5:K37`

When i go into the named range sidebar, i've tried to change the formula to say:
Range1 = `'Sheet1'!$K$5:$K$36`
but the $ go away immediately upon hitting ok

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the indirect function. If cell A1 contains the first row of the range (5 in your case) and A2 contains the last (36), if you are looking for the sum of the range you can use the following formula:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!k"&A1&":k"&a2))
```

If you add more rows to your range, the formula will not change its results.

Comment: I cannot use a function to name a range, but this did give me the idea to pull the range to another sheet using a query for only certain cells (or use the indirect function).  Then i'll name the pulled data's range. This should work.  Thanks!